# In powershell, getting pre-invocation arguments of a function after calling param?

Tags: powershell

Let's say I have a function that I call like this:

```
myfunction -msg1 'this is message 1'  -msg2 'this is message2'
```

And here is my function:

```
function myfunction {
    param([string]$msg1, [string]$msg2)

    #HOW WOULD I Get the pre-invocation argument the function here? that is:
    $preinvoke = @( "-msg1", 'this is message 1', '-msg2', 'this is message2')

    write-host "You called this command like this: myfunction $preinvoke"
}
```

Is there a way to automatically set $preinvoke based on there real flags to the function after calling param?  My impression is that param eats all the arguments... I want the list of pre-invokation arguments to the function after calling param.

Comment: "I want the list of pre-invocation arguments" - why?

Comment: `$PSBoundParameters` or `$MyInvocation.BoundParameters` should give you what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `$MyInvocation` automatic variable:

```
function Test-Invocation
{
  param([string]$msg1, [string]$msg2)

  # $MyInvocation.Line will give you the originating call
  $originalInvocation = $MyInvocation.Line
  Write-Host "Original invocation: ${originalInvocation}"

  # Which you can then parse/tokenize again if need be
  $tokens = @()
  $AST = [System.Management.Automation.Language.Parser]::ParseInput($originalInvocation, [ref]$tokens, [ref]$null)

  Write-Host "Original Invocation contains the following tokens:"
  foreach($token in $tokens){
    Write-Host ("  {0,15} (flags: {1,20}): '{2}'" -f $token.Kind,$token.TokenFlags,$token.Text)
  }
}
```

Then use/test like this:

```
PS ~> Test-Invocation -msg1 'this is message 1'  -msg2 'this is message2'
Original Invocation contains the following tokens:
          Generic (flags:          CommandName): 'Test-Invocation'
        Parameter (flags:                 None): '-msg1'
    StringLiteral (flags:   ParseModeInvariant): ''this is message 1''
        Parameter (flags:                 None): '-msg2'
    StringLiteral (flags:   ParseModeInvariant): ''this is message2''
       EndOfInput (flags:   ParseModeInvariant): ''
```